Change (horizontal) line length for single legend entry in pgfplots
How do I change the line length of an individual entry in a pgfplots legend? I cannot use the solution provided here, as I also have other custom markers in the legend, and this screws up the vertical spacing. Thanks in advance!
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/ylabel style={rotate=-90},
    legend style={nodes={scale=0.7, transform shape}},
    every axis/.append style={
        label style={font=\footnotesize},
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize}  
    },
    % legend image code/.code={\draw[mark repeat=2,mark phase=2] plot coordinates {(0,0) (2mm,0) (3mm,0)};},  % <- This does not work, it screws up the vertical spacing
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        height=60mm,
        width=70mm,
        xmin = -0.4,
        xmax = 0.4,
        ymin = -0.6,
        ymax = 0.6,
        xlabel={$x_{1}$},
        ylabel={$x_{2}$},
        xmajorticks=false,
        ymajorticks=false,
        legend cell align={left},
        legend columns=1,
        legend style={
            at={($(1,1) + (-1.5mm,-1.5mm)$)},
            anchor=north east
        }
    ]   
        % First region
        \addplot [draw=blue, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.2, forget plot] coordinates {
            (0.3,0.6) (-0.3,0.1) (-0.3,-0.6) (0.3,-0.1) (0.3,0.6)
        };
        \addlegendimage{draw=blue, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.2, only marks, mark=square*, mark size=3pt}
        % Second region
        \addplot [draw=red, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2, forget plot] coordinates {
            (-0.5,-1.1) (-0.2,-1.1) (0.5,1.1) (0.2,1.1) (-0.5,-1.1)
        };
        \addlegendimage{draw=red, fill=red, fill opacity=0.2, only marks, mark=square*, mark size=3pt}
        % Add trajectory
        \addplot[forget plot, draw=green, mark=*, mark options={draw=green,fill=green,scale=0.5}] coordinates {
            (0,0) (0.1,0.1) (0.15,0.18) (0.03,0.45)
        };
        \addlegendimage{draw=green, mark=*, mark options={draw=green,fill=green,scale=0.5}}
        % Add legend
        \legend{$\,{X}_{0}$,$\,\mathrm{ker}(\boldsymbol{C}) \oplus {B}_{\epsilon}$,$\,{X}_{\textnormal{reach}}$,$\,\mathrm{ker}(\boldsymbol{C})$,$\,\boldsymbol{x}_{k}$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

OUTPUT:

DESIRED:


Here is the corrected legend image code:
legend image code/.code={
    \draw[%
            /pgfplots/mesh=false,%
            % reset bar options. This is to address the strange
            % backwards compatibility handling implemented by
            % \pgfplots@install@local@bar@handlers (see its docs).
            % This should not hurt at all since 'line legend' is
            % unsuitable for bar plots anyway.
            bar width=3pt,%
            bar shift=0pt,%
            %
            mark repeat=2,%
            mark phase=2]
            plot coordinates {
                (0cm,0cm)
                (0.15cm,0cm)
                (0.3cm,0cm)%
            };%
},

modified from the source code pgfplots.code.tex line 2008.
I do not show the complete compilable code as there are several things I would do different/clean. I would not use \addlegendimage (forget plot or \legend) except for special cases. \addlegendentry already uses the correct style from the plot and there is even a area legend style.


Many thanks; it works like a charm! It's also good to know area legend exists, although when I use \addlegendentry with the former, I run into the same problem where now the area legend entry is too wide (can I change this one as well).
